# Very skittish cat, spends most of his day hiding - how could I help him?

Tags: cats, behavior

We got our kitten about a year ago, he was always skittish but it feels like he's getting worse and worse.

At the beginning he was always out and about. He was a bit scared of our friends coming by but he approached them and even played fetch with them.

Now he spends most of his day under the couch, he comes out around 7-8pm and he's very affectionate and wants pets etc. But the slightest noise and he bolts. Like even if I'm wearing a different pair of shoes that makes a different sound he's not familiar with, he bolts under the couch or a bed.

We also have an older cat, he's 11 years old and they were never good friends. I kinda feel like this contributed to him being terrorized.

Lastly, we have family staying over for the next month and our kitten is having a real hard time. He comes out really late, at like 9-10pm. He doesn't eat anything or use the toilet the whole day. He hides in our bedroom and if he hears the voices or even their footsteps, he bolts.

When we took him to the vet's a few months back for shots, she suggested to give him some green tea pills to calm him but I wasn't able to give them to him (or think it's a good idea). I'm afraid if I try to force the pill down, he'll start being skittish of me too. RC's Pill Assist is a no go too, he just licks off the food and leaves the pill behind.

What could we do to help him be more social and less skittish?+

Edit: Forgot to mention, both of our cats are indoor cats and both male castrated.

Comment: Have a look here: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/12040/my-rescue-kitten-is-afraid-of-people-and-hides-in-the-basement/12045#12045

Comment: @Allerleirauh Thanks, that's helpful. I'll try the treat and toy solution.

Comment: https://youtu.be/nZRu8zlRTi0 An advice video on this exact problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My rescue kitten is afraid of people and hides in the basement](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/12040/my-rescue-kitten-is-afraid-of-people-and-hides-in-the-basement) (automated comment, when marking the question as dublicate)

Comment: When you make some improvement to the situation you can answer your own question and tell others with the same question what had helped your cat :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a kitty who sounds very similar to yours! His name is Grump Nugget (for obvious reasons). He is the most timid cat and yet the most affectionate cat that we have, and he is about 1y&3mo old.

We started using ComfortZone (FeliWay knockoff) diffusers and they seemed to help him come out slightly more often, but it wasn't to a point where we felt like he was comfortable.

I ended up taking him to the vet and we discussed anxiety medicine. At first, I was very opposed as he didn't have a choice in the situation, I couldn't get verbal feedback from him about how the medicine was making him feel, and I assumed that anxiety meds would mean a constant level of sedation. My vet did a great job explaining the options and, to my surprise, there are anxiety medicines for cats that work similarly to SSRIs for humans (no sedation!). We've watched his mood, weight, and socialization with the other cats over the few months he's been on it and there have been no negative effects, only drastic positive ones.

He has started to come out from under the bed even when we have people over! Usually he will sit near the doorway and kind of watch over the happenings in the living area, but every once in a while he gets brave enough to swiftly pass through the area to get a better look. He's become more vocal with us (audible excitement when we get his food out or come home from work - it's so cute!) and spends more time playing with the other cats than he used to. He's out most of the time that we are home and active, but still gets a little reclusive with company over.

Overall, I think your best bet is a vet trip. Don't be too scared about cost - Nugget's medicine is only $13/mo (and I believe it actually costed less than that for the refills we bought through Chewy!).